# ADO.NET EF - using LINQ 2 Entity and GroupBy to distinct by two columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I know the title is a little confusing but the problem is very straight forward. I am using `Entity Framework` and `Code First` approach. I have those two entities with relation 1:N. The uniqueness of the records comes from the combination of two columns - `Code` + `CountryID`. First I thought that `Code` itself will be unique files so my query for getting distinct records was looking like this:

```
IList<SoleColor> soles = SoleColorService.All()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Sole.Code)
                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList();
```

But now it occurs that doing so I lose those records where the `Code` (or to be exact - the `Sole.Code`) is the same but the `CountryID` is different. What I need is to change my query so it returns all records where `Code` + `CountryID` is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by an anonymous type:

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.Sole.Code, x.Sole.CountryID })
```

BTW: Using `FirstOrDefault` on groups returned from a `GroupBy` doesn't make sense. Every group returned by a `GroupBy` contains at least one element, so using `First` is guaranteed to always succeed.

Comment: Thanks, gonna accept your answer. As for `First()` this is why i changed it - `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.` (The error I get when I try with `First()`)

Comment: @Leron: Ah, ok. I wasn't aware of this EF limitation.